# How to write Jquery in anoher Page

Tags: jquery

references

```
<script src="JQuery/SiteQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="JQuery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

and the code

```
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('.scrollup').click(function () {
                            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800, "easeOutCubic");
                            return false;
                        });

                    });
```

When i put this code in Html file its works, but not in separate file which is 'SiteQuery' which the first reference

any reason why, or how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sholud be in this order

```
<script src="JQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="JQuery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="JQuery/SiteQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

First you should declare the `JQUERY` library file and then `JQUERY UI MIN` library file and then your JS file